# Restore / Show Outliner again

Tags: mesh

When I start Blender, I am shown the Outliner on the right side:

[image: Outliner screen]

Somehow I very often manage to hide it. I think it happens when I unwrap and have the "UV Edit" window shown on the left side of Blender.

How to restore/show it again?

Comment: This editor window is called Outliner. So are you hiding Outliner itself or hierarchy in the Outliner ? If this is the first case, then [look here for more info](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel), if the second, press `+` and `-` on Numpad

Comment: @MrZak Sorry, none of your 2 proposals helped me. I have hidden the outliner itself. Pressing + and - on the numpad caused zoom in and zoom out. But thank you anyway.

Comment: If you have the Outliner hidden, then, as I said, to reveal its appearence you should look into the question I linked. Using that, you can find out how to open editors you'd like (the Logic editor is discussed there; you should search for Outliner editor in the dropdown menu)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/is-there-a-quick-way-to-reset-a-blend-files-windows-and-settings-to-default. and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortcut for the outliner window is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd>.

For the shortcuts to other windows see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17937/1853)

Answer (score 3):

When I hide the Outliner by accident, I get it back with **Ctrl+Up Arrow**. 
(**Ctrl+Down Arrow** hides it)