# Object is too dark

Tags: rendering

Right, so I tracked a clip and put a cube on it, and managed to get shadows appearing, except the cube is too dark. It doesn't matter how close, or how intense the lights are, wont get any brighter than a dark green.

Heres a pre-rendered:

[image]

And here's it rendered:

[image]

I want it to be a really light shade of green, but it won't budge.
Also, the material settings are set to a really light shade of green, and it still doesn't work.

***ALSO***

My scene tab is gone. Completely gone, I accidently got rid of it and don't know how to get it back. If someone can tell me how to fix this, thanks.
[image]

***EDIT***

I managed to get the scene tab back, it was called the Outliner and i just didn't know. Heres my material settings:

[image]

Also, the .BLEND if you need it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzgDIjhDOu6Eb0FfRVhRZFZ6MWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Show us your material settings for the cube.

Comment: For the "scene tab" (outliner), see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35589/599

Comment: Hi, please only ask one question at a time. If you need to ask multiple questions ask it as a separate post. E.g. in this example, asking about the outliner should have been separate.

Comment: ^ Sorry, I'll remember that.

Answer (score 3):

### Layers

Both lamps are in a **Scene Layer** that is not included in a **Layer** for the *foreground* **Render Layer**, so their contribute is ignored while rendering.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I would suggest to put all the lamps in a different layer and make it active in all the Render's layer's Layer.