# Reseting blender gui in a loaded model

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

I have tried to model my first object in blender after watching online tutorials. But when I came to adding modifiers, it turn out, that I can#t find them at any sidepanel in blender. Is there are way to reset these panels to the point when you create a new object?[image: my current blender gui when opening this model]

Comment: possible dupicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/is-there-a-quick-way-to-reset-a-blend-files-windows-and-settings-to-default

Answer (score 2):

While loading a scene unclick **Load UI** option:

[image]

If your file has already opened, you need to reload startup file first (**File** -> **New**)